# Are the only rational functions those that are explicitly written as a polynomial over a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Is $f(x) = \dfrac{3x}{x^{-2}-4}$ a rational function?

On the one hand, the denominator of $f(x)$ is **not** a polynomial, so $f$ is **not** a rational function.

On the other hand, we can multiply both the numerator and the denominator of $f(x)$ by $x^2$ to get $g(x) = \dfrac{3x^3}{1-4x^2}$, which is clearly a rational function.

Comment: Is $\frac{x-2}{x^2-4}$ defined at x=2?

Comment: The functions are not equivalent. The first one is not defined at $x=0$

Comment: I'd say the answer is no, because $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$ whereas $g(x)$ is not.

Comment: So I'd say the conditions for being a rational function are... it can be simplified to $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ form, and the only places where the function is undefined are the zeros of $Q(x)$.

Comment: If we redefine $g(x)$ such that its domain does **not** include $x = 0$, $f$ and $g$ become equivalent. Can we now say that $f$ is also a rational function?

Comment: @RichardMiller. No. That doesn't change $f(x)$ which remains undefined at 0. So it remains not a rational function. Redefining $g(x)$ so that it's domain does not include 0, would just make $g(x)$ the same as $f(x)$, ie: $g(x)$ is then also not a rational function.

Comment: Is $\,\frac{e^x}{e^x}\,$ a rational function? My guess is yes.

Comment: @Somos, agreed.

Comment: @Peter: one can take care of that by modifying $g(x)$ to be $3x^4/(x - 4x^3)$. This is a rational function which is not defined at $0$.